# Dynamic named credentials Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I need to update the permissions of a Drive document from Salesforce.

I wanted to use Named Credentials, but I didn't find any way of building a call like this one:

[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{documentId}/permissions](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%7BdocumentId%7D/permissions)

where {documentId} is a dynamic value.

I've seen that it is possible to add a prefix, but actually even if I create a Named Credential with only *https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files*, when I call it from my Apex class I get a permission error.

Is there a way to achieve what I would like or I need to change approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What exactly error are you getting? Salesforce security about not having access to class X? Something about callouts not allowed from triggers? You're sure it works with hardcoded document id?

Should be possible to make the named credential point to `https://www.googleapis.com` or `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/` and then add the rest of the endpoint in Apex. If it throws errors - maybe Drive's API is special, you'd need to read up.

```
String endpoint = 'callout:MyNamedCredential' + '/abc123/permissions';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
```

I have something like that:

`Named credential pointing to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json`

and then

```
static final String ENDPOINT = 'callout:GoogleMaps?key={0}&latlng={1}&result_type=premise%7Cstreet_address';
String apiKey = SomeCustomSetting__c.getInstance().GoogleApiKey__c;
String latLng = '60.23,11.17';

req.setEndpoint(String.format(ENDPOINT, new List<String>{apiKey, latLng}));
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

You could also look into "[Files Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_admin_files_connect.htm&type=5)" API I guess.

Comment: I receive this error: "System.UnexpectedException: You don't have permission to view this data, enter credentials for the named credential in your personal settings. Or ask your Salesforce admin for help." when I do the call. If I use the whole url in the named credential (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/) it works perfectly, but if I break it and I leave in the named credential only 'https://www.googleapis.com' I get that error

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how's that NC configured. Sign in with certificate? Google account credentials? something else? Mask the sensitive bits. Have you tried https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/use-of-named-credentials-seem-to-be-tied-to-external-data-source ?